# .htaccess domain directory does not resolve domain.com/domain properly

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have 2 domains that point to the same IP `foo.com` and `bar.com`

I don't have access to setting up a virtual host for the domains but I have managed to create `.htaccess` rules so that it is setup like this.

- foo.com points to / directory
- bar.com points to /bar directory

Having the setup above now I could have different `index.html` files for accessing the root of the domain.

This is the rule I implemented for `bar.com`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bar\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !bar/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ bar/$1 [L]
```

The above rule works perfectly however when I navigate to `bar.com/bar` it doesn't give me a `404` but instead it still points to the root of my `bar` directory.

So, I created another `RewriteCond` to handle such issue.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bar\.com$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "(GET|POST) \/bar\/ HTTP/"
```

While the `RewriteCond` works perfectly. I am not sure what rewrite rule I would write so that when the user visits `bar.com/bar` it would point to the `/bar/bar` directory and thus would give me a `404`

I tried the `RewriteRule` below but it doesn't seem to work

```
RewriteRule ^bar/(.*)$ bar/bar/$1  [L,QSA]
```

So I temporarily created a redirect to the main `bar.com` domain.

```
RewriteRule ^bar/(.*)$ http://bar.com/$1 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?bar\.com$
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "(GET|POST) \/bar\/(.*) HTTP/"
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bar/$1 [L]
```